# How do I join one table onto another where userid = userid but only for that date?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having, having-clause

I'm looking to take the total time a user worked on each batch at his workstation, the total estimated work that was completed, the amount the user was paid, and how many failures the user has had for each day this year. If I can join all of this into one query then I can use it in excel and format things nicely in pivot tables and such.

EDIT: I've realized that is only possible to do this in multiple queries so I have narrowed my scope down to this:

```
SELECT batch_log.userid,
batches.operation_id,
SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(ramses.batch_log.time_elapsed)),
SUM(ramses.tasks.estimated_nonrecurring + ramses.tasks.estimated_recurring),
DATE(start_time)
FROM batch_log
JOIN batches ON batch_log.batch_id=batches.id
JOIN ramses.tasks   ON ramses.batch_log.batch_id=ramses.tasks.batch_id
JOIN protocase.tblusers on ramses.batch_log.userid = protocase.tblusers.userid
WHERE DATE(ramses.batch_log.start_time) > "2011-01-01"
AND protocase.tblusers.active = 1
GROUP BY userid, batches.operation_id, start_time
ORDER BY start_time, userid ASC
```

The cross join was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general a `Having` clause is used to filter the results of your `Group by` - for example, only reporting those who were paid for more than 24 hours in a day (`HAVING SUM(ramses.timesheet_detail.paidTime) > 24`).  Unless you need to perform filtering of aggregate results, you shouldn't need a `having` clause at all.
Most of those conditions should be moved into a `where` clause, or as part of the joins, for two reasons - 1) Filtering should in general be done as soon as possible, to limit the work the query needs to perform. 2) If the filtering is already done, restating it may cause the query to perform additional, unneeded work.
From what I've seen so far, it appears that you're trying to roll things up by the day - try changing the last column in the `group by` clause to `date(ramses.batch_log.start_time)`, or you're grouping by (what I assume is) a timestamp.

---

EDIT:
About schema names - yes, you can name them in the `from` and `join` sections.  Often, too, the query may be able to resolve the needed schemas based on some default search list (how or if this is set up depends on your database).
Here is how I would have reformatted the query:

```
SELECT tblusers.userid, operations.name AS name,
SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(batch_log.time_elapsed)) AS time_elapsed,
SUM(tasks.estimated_nonrecurring + tasks.estimated_recurring) AS total_estimated,
SUM(timesheet_detail.paidTime) as hours_paid,
DATE(start_time) as date_paid
FROM tblusers
JOIN batch_log 
ON tblusers.userid = batch_log.userid 
AND DATE(batch_log.start_time) >= "2011-01-01" 
JOIN batches 
ON batch_log.batch_id = batches.id
JOIN operations 
ON operations.id = batches.operation_id
JOIN tasks
ON batches.id = tasks.batch_id
JOIN timesheet_detail 
ON tblusers.userid = timesheet_detail.userid 
AND batch_log.start_time = timesheet_detail.for_day
AND DATE(timesheet_detail.for_day) = DATE(start_time)
WHERE tblusers.departmentid = 8
GROUP BY tblusers.userid, name, DATE(batch_log.start_time)     
ORDER BY date_paid ASC
```

Of particular concern is the `batch_log.start_time = timesheet_detail.for_day` line, which is comparing (what are implied to be) timestamps.  Are these really equal?  I expect that one or both of these should be wrapped in a `date()` function.

As for why you may be getting unexpected data - you appear to have eliminated some of your join conditions.  Without knowing the exact setup and use of your database, I cannot give the exact reason for your results (or even able to say they are wrong), but I think the fact that you join to the `operations` table without any `join` condition is probably to blame - if there are 2 records in that table, it will double all of your previous results, and it looks like there may be 12.  You also removed `operations.name` from the `group by` clause, which may or may not give you the results you want.  I would look into the rest of your table relationships, and see if there are any further restrictions that need to be made.

Comment: Yes. Sorry my question was phrased so shitty. I'm so out of my element with this sql stuff. I've only been a developer for about 2 years now and most of my sql has been through rails (which does 90%) of the work. I know i have a ways to go with sql.

Comment: Also, I know it's probably hard to read a file with no indentation but I'm really just not sure of proper coding style in SQL

Comment: That's all right, we all have to start somewhere.  Some SQL style comments: In general, I always attempt to put relationship links into joins, `AND`ed and `OR`ed appropriately (this makes the relationships more apparent), and tend to leave the `where` clause for criteria used solely for the table listed in the `from` clause.  Also, why do you have a blank string in the `group by` clause - as this is constant, it shouldn't have any effect.  Consider removing your schema names from the statement, as this will allow the tables to be moved, if necessary, without updating the statement.

Comment: As far as the schema names, where do I declare them so that I can use them without naming the full path to them? In the from and the join section?

Relationship links though, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Also blank string was just mispasted in there.

Comment: The problem in this case is that you aren't restricting your join to the operations table, which is making it give the summation of results for _all_ operations.  Re-add `ON operations.id = batches.operation_id` after the join, and see if that helps.  You will also need to add the `batches` table back to the statement (with the necessary joins) to restrict this properly.

Comment: I wanted to use that cross join so that I could get an entry for every operation for each user but I guess I should have just been doing it differently all along.

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance.  Keep experimenting with it, you may be able to get more data with just the one query.

Comment: @X-Zero let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1013/discussion-between-dah-and-x-zero)